# Defining parent class methods' default arguments

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I would like class B to initialize (abstract) class A's methods with default parameters. How can one do this ? For example this doesn't work:

```py
class A:
    DEFAULT = 10
    def meth(default=DEFAULT):
        print(default)

class B(A):
    DEFAULT = 20
B().meth() # prints 10 and displays 10 as default instead of 20
```

I also tried:

```py
class A:
    DEFAULT = 10
    def meth(default=DEFAULT):
        print(default)
class B(A):
    A.DEFAULT = 20
B().meth()  # prints 10 and displays 10 as default instead of 20
```

Is there a way to "re-initialize" class A inside B to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you trying to redefine the super class so that subsequent instantiations of that class (or subclasses) will use a new default?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing up a few misconceptions first:

- A is not abstract, it's a regular class
- You've defined `DEFAULT` as class variables.  Is this your intention?
- Your methods are improperly formatted.  If you intend them to be instance methods, the first argument must be `self`

This is one solution:

```
class A:
    DEFAULT = 10
    def meth(self, default=None):
        if default is None:
            default = self.DEFAULT
        print(default)

class B(A):
    DEFAULT = 20


b = B()
b.meth() # prints 20
```

In the above, I've left `DEFAULT` as a class variable and `meth` an instance variable (which may or may not be what you intended).

Comment: This works but the methods' default arguments end up being None instead of DEFAULT, so it is not a full solution

Comment: I think you'll find this has the behavior you're looking for.    DEFAULT *does* function as a default.

Comment: I agree with you. What I don't like about this is that the default is not explicitly displayed in the function call. Rather the user would have to dig up into the docstring to know about it. Also, sorry I want to  +1 your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet

Comment: "You've defined DEFAULT as class variables. Is this your intention?" -> not in particular, I just want to initialize several methods from a parent class (abstract or not) with the same default parameter, whatever the way

Answer (score -1):

Replying myself. This has the behavior I'm looking for but I don't like it very much. It forces one to explicitly override each parent method in the subclass, which can be tedious with many methods

```py
class A:
    DEFAULT=10
    def meth(self,default=DEFAULT):
        print(default)
        
class B(A):
    DEFAULT=20
    def meth(self,default=DEFAULT):
        return super().meth(default=default)
B().meth()
```

EDIT: @anon01 correctly remarks class A should only be used as an abstract parent class with this solution otherwise DEFAULT might be misleading

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractproperty, abstractmethod
class A(ABC):
    @abstractproperty
    def DEFAULT(): 
        ''' Default integer parameter to implement '''
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    @abstractmethod
    def meth(self,default=DEFAULT):
        print(default)
        
class B(A):
    DEFAULT=20
    def meth(self,default=DEFAULT):
        return super().meth(default=default)
B().meth()
```

Comment: This will cause strange (buggy) behavior.  For example: `a = A(); a.meth(); A.DEFAULT=999; a.meth() # returns 10; a.DEFAULT = 888; a.meth() # returns 10`

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I edited the answer so it is clear class A is only meant to be subclassed